# Problems in computing commutators in quantizing Dirac field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator, dirac-equation

When I read articles on how to quantize Dirac Field, like on page 53 of *An introduction to Quantum Field Theory* written by Michael E. Peskin and Daniel V. Schroeder, it is defined as 
$$\psi(\vec{x})=\int{\frac{d^3p}{2\pi^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}}} e^{i\vec{p}\vec{x}}\Sigma_{s}(a^s_\vec{p}u^s(\vec{p})+b^s_{-\vec{p}}v^s(-\vec{p})). \tag{3.87}$$
It postulates$^1$ $$[a^r_{\vec{p}},a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}]=[b^r_{\vec{p}},b^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}]=(2\pi)^3 \delta ^{(3)}(\vec{p}-\vec{q})\delta^{rs}.\tag{3.88}$$
When commutators like $[\psi(x),\psi^\dagger(y)]$ or $\{\psi(x),\psi^\dagger(y)\}$ are computed, in the integral I get terms like

$$\{a^r_\vec{p}u^r(\vec{p}),a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}u^{s\dagger}(\vec{q})\}=a^r_\vec{p}u^r(\vec{p})a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}u^{s\dagger}(\vec{q})+a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}u^{s\dagger}(\vec{q})a^r_\vec{p}u^r(\vec{p})$$

I assume $[u^r(\vec{p}),a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}]$ etc commute, although I doubt it, I got
$$
\begin{align}&=a^r_\vec{p}a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}u^r(\vec{p})u^{s\dagger}(\vec{q})+a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}a^r_\vec{p}u^{s\dagger}(\vec{q})u^r(\vec{p})\\
&=a^r_\vec{p}a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}u^r(\vec{p})u^{s\dagger}(\vec{q})+a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}a^r_\vec{p}u^r(\vec{p})u^{s\dagger}(\vec{q})-a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}a^r_\vec{p}u^r(\vec{p})u^{s\dagger}(\vec{q})+a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}a^r_\vec{p}u^{s\dagger}(\vec{q})u^r(\vec{p})\\
&=[a^r_\vec{p},a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}]u^r(\vec{p})u^{s\dagger}(\vec{q})+a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}a^r_\vec{p}[u^{s\dagger}(\vec{q}),u^r(\vec{p})]\end{align}$$

it is often, in the text, only terms like $[a^r_\vec{p},a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}]u^r(p)u^{s\dagger}(q)$ is remained in the integral, but I do not know why $a^{s\dagger}_\vec{q}a^r_\vec{p}[u^{s\dagger}(\vec{q}),u^r(\vec{p})]$ vanishes... is it a posulate that it vanishes?

---

$^1$ Later in eq. (3.97) they change the commuators into anticommutators, but that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

Put spinor indices on everything and then you will realise that $u^s_\alpha$ is just a function of momentum, i.e. a
$c$-number, and $c$-numbers commute.